# JavaFX shift+Scrollwheel always return 0.0

Tags: javafx, shift, scrollwheel

I built a custom calendar control with many navegability features, the only issue im facing now is the month jump on shift+scrollwheel.

```
mainb.setOnScroll(e->{
            mainb.requestFocus();
            System.out.println(e.getDeltaY());
            if(e.isShiftDown()){
                if(e.getDeltaY()>0)
                    prev.fire();
                else
                    next.fire();
            }else if(e.isControlDown()){
                System.out.println(e.getDeltaY());
                if(e.getDeltaY()>0)
                    prevDay();
                else
                    nextDay();
            }else{
                if(e.getDeltaY()>0)
                    prevWeek();
                else
                    nextWeek();
            }
        });
```

[code + component + console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUgSh.png)

```
            if(e.isShiftDown()){
                if(e.getDeltaY()>0)//always 0.0
                    prev.fire();//never fired
                else
                    next.fire();//always fired
            }
```

Comment: have you tried to test to see if its an issue with shift and scroll wheel? try disabling its automatic function by adding `e.consume()` before `System.out.println`, alternatively for a test try using another key (not Shift and see if you get the same results)

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago and was not sure whether this is a bug in JavaFX or whether this is so by design. I finally switched to use the alt-key instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the shift key is used to switch from
vertical to horizontal scrolling (see: [bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097935)).
Therefore, `e.getDeltaY()` will return 0 when the shift key is pressed.
Use `e.getDeltaX()` in this case.